# Why do I get "Errno::ECONNREFUSED" with 'net/http' in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, net-http

I am trying to parse an XML file from a URL. When I try something like this:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'rubygems'
require 'xmlsimple'

url = 'http://my-address.com/xmltest/note.xml'
xml_data = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url)).body
```

Everything works, but only when I do this outside of my Rails project. If I try including this file in my Rails 3 project and parsing it there, I get the error `"Errno::ECONNREFUSED in [controller]" - Connection refused - connect(2)`.

My problem is the following: I don't know how to install the `net/http` component. I am looking for it on http://www.rubygems.org, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Net::HTTP`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/net/1.9.2/frames) is part of Ruby's standard library. You can use `require 'net/http'` to load it.

Rather than use `Net::HTTP`, which is fairly low-level for what you want to do, I'd recommend using Ruby's [`Open::URI`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/open-uri/1.9.2/frames).

If you are moving a lot of HTTP data, you might want to look into something like HTTPClient or Curb or Typhoeus, which are designed for heavy-weight use and save you the trouble of having to write it all using `Net::HTTP`.

Regarding the `ECONNREFUSED` error: you might want to capture the HTTPResponse returned from `get_response`, then check its status before trying to read the body. The way you're doing it now doesn't let you react to a failed request.

Comment: I am receiving the same error, however it is before get_response even returns. I can't figure out how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the problem is that you can't connect to the HTTP-server.
You could try checking that you can access the URL in a browser.

Comment: before checking the HTTP-server, i would verify if Internet is actually connected :)